# Powershell get-aduser replacing null attribute while exporting to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

my apologies if this has been asked many times before but I could use a hand with the command below. I am extracting Active Directory user information to a CSV but can use a hand with the correct code to replace the telePhoneNumber field with a fixed number of "555-555-5555" if it is null. I guess our organization has a lot of users without a phone number, and when I try to use the csv for our intended project, I can't because it errors and fails to grab the user if they do not have a phone number supplied. Is this possible to do?

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "GROUPNAME" | Get-ADUser -Properties * | select @{N='UserName';E={$_.UserPrincipalName}},@{N='FirstName';E={"" + $_.givenName}},@{N='LastName';E={"" + $_.sn}},@{N='BusPhone';E={$_.telePhoneNumber}} | Export-csv c:\intel\thegroup.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do whatever you like in the expression block of a calculated property.

Try changing:

```
@{N='BusPhone';E={$_.telePhoneNumber}}
```

to:

```
@{N='BusPhone';E={if($_.telePhoneNumber){$_.telePhoneNumber}else{'555-555-5555'}}}
```

Comment: You are my hero, I was trying something similar but must have been formatting my if statement in correctly. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm pretty rusty with this website, how to mark yours as the correct answer ?

Comment: @JustinV You're welcome! There shold be an outline of a checkmark on the left of my answer - click it to accept :-)